# Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2013 for Xamarin.Forms XAML Cross-Platform Mobile App

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms, intellisense

Recently I installed Xamarin studio verison 5.8.2(build 7) on VS 2013 for developing Cross-Platform Mobile App. I have autocomplete or Intellisense issue in XAML. I tried reinstalling, repairing, and other suggestions found on google but Intellisense in XAML didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

After spending few hours in reinstalling, repairing, and following other suggestions. 
Finally I found Solution to this problem from this link
[Xamarin.Forms.Intellisense](http://www.cazzulino.com/mobileessentials.html)

Now XAML intellisense in Xamarin.Forms started working as expected.

Comment: You can also use Resharper 9.0+.